# why is domain API deprecated in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why is [domain API](https://nodejs.org/api/domain.html) deprecated in Node.js?

I found it handy to catch errors in context of a incoming web request rather than exception boiling up to the level of process.

Also, is there any alternative to domain APIs that can be now be used?

Comment: Using domains in production in 2018: https://medium.com/@the1mills/using-node-js-domains-in-production-797105a4c302

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[zone.js](https://github.com/btford/zone.js/) is mentioned as an alternative [in another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149785/alternative-to-domain-in-nodejs). Angular2 uses it heavily. (I have no personal experience with zone.js in Node.js.)

Answer (score 19):

[Node.js issue #66: deprecate domains](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/66):

> The problem isn't the user experience of
>   domains, as you say the API is simple and users are generally happy
>   with it, but the consequences domains have in maintenance and
>   complications for the node.js core code – that seemingly simple API
>   impacts all of the code base in a too negative way.
>
> Domains in its current form must go. That's certain. What the
>   alternative is, no one knows.
>
> > I don't get how we can deprecate something that covers a use case that cannot be covered otherwise, without providing clear (and ready)
> >     alternatives.
>
> If we flip that the other way around. We know domains must go, and
>   will have to be removed at some point soon-ish. Would you prefer there
>   be no indication of this?

The linked issue also mentions (the lack of) alternatives.

Comment: They at the very least should make it a node module so it can be plugged in.

Comment: domains are an essential feature of node.js core and deprecating them is a bad idea because it is doubtful any alternative can implemented in a different way; so any alternative will be no more maintenable than domains as they are now.