# domainsEnabled client option removed in node mongodb driver 4.0

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-nodejs-driver

Node mongodb native driver version 3.7 provides a `domainsEnabled` connection option (as described in [3.7 documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.7/api/global.html#MongoClientOptions))

> Enable the wrapping of the callback in the current domain, disabled by default to avoid perf hit

However, I don't find a similar option in [4.0 release](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.7/interfaces/MongoClientOptions.html)

Why has it been removed? Is there any workaround to have the same functionality with 4.0?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe useful https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-1974

Comment: Maybe useful https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/pull/2603

Comment: Apparently they took nodejs domain deprecation too optimistically. 14 major versions later it's still deprecated...

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Alex Blex. However, as far as I understand nodejs domains are not yet deprecated, but in "pending deprecation" status as far as I understand by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49494211/replacement-for-domain-in-nodejs and https://nodejs.org/api/domain.html

Comment: ah, indeed, I missed the small print. So it's been in the "pending deprecation" for some 7 years now... one says "There is nothing so permanent as a temporary fix". May be raise a feature request to revert the change.